# how to change installation path of pip command? How to set default python directory for installation of packages using pip command

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my Django Application on AWS EC2, which is running properly. I dont know what happen but its giving me error for `django.core.management` as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/myproject/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I googled and searched on SO answers also and gone through all the possible answers. The issue I am facing is, I am running cron jobs in my application which I set in `settings.py`. Due to this error it is not get executed on time. But I wondered that the other application I can access and its running properly. only the thing at the time of cronjob it giving this error.
One more issue I am facing is `pip` command is not working with root user

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX ~]$ sudo pip install django
sudo: pip2.7: command not found
```

it is runnning with ec2-user. but due to lack of permissions it is not able to install or update the modules.
 I have two versions of python `python2.6` and `python2.7`, whenever I try to install modules it by default goes in `python2.6` directory. I want to set the python version 2.7 default and the modules also should install in 2.7 directory.
Please suggest me how to resolve. some similar question was there I applied all the answers but not worked. Please tell me how can I resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the installation path right from command line (terminal)

`pip install --target=required_path required_package`

Comment: I tried this, but what happening due to lack of write permission it is not installed on specified path, and when I use `sudo` command then it gives me error that `pip` command is not found.

Comment: hmm... it's weird:) 
Have you also try: 

`easy_install django`, 
`easy_install --install-dir path_to_your_folder django`, 
`conda install django` (if Anaconda pre-installed)?

Comment: yes, easy_install I tried, but not worked. One thing that I want to do is, to set python2.7 directory as default installation directory for all package/module related with python instead of python2.6